# EE3 Image cropping when image is uploaded

Tags: ee2, image, ee3, image-path, crop

So I know EE3 have a built in image manipulation where you can either crop or constrain the image.

[image: Image Manipulation CP]

I'm using [picturefill](https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill) to swap images for Desktop, Tablet and Mobile. But the images for some reason are not showing up. Get empty src for images. I believe there is a special way to display images for Desktop, Tablet and Mobile in my case.

```
{banner}
        <picture class="bg-image">
            <!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->
            <source srcset="{banner:home:desktop}" media="(min-width: 1000px)">
            <source srcset="{banner:home:tablet}" media="(min-width: 760px)">
            <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
            <img srcset="{banner:home:mobile}" alt="" />
        </picture>
{/banner}
```

Can you spot what am I doing wrong here? Basically images that are uploaded I need to crop them to 3 sizes and then display them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that your syntax is incorrect in a few ways.

1. Within a File field tag pair you should *not* prefix variables with the parent tag (`banner:`).
2. You should *not* include the directory name (`home:`) as prefix segment in the variable names.
3. You're using lowercase for your manipulation names in your template, but uppercase in your settings (I'm not *positive* this will throw things off, but you should always be consistent, and make them match).

Your code should be revised to look like this:

```
{banner}
    <picture class="bg-image">
        <!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->
        <source srcset="{url:Desktop}" media="(min-width: 1000px)">
        <source srcset="{url:Tablet}" media="(min-width: 760px)">
        <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
        <img srcset="{url:Mobile}" alt="" />
    </picture>
{/banner}
```

Check the [docs on File fields](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/fieldtypes/file.html) for more info on the variables, and examples.